# Detect if Jasmine failed via Bash

Tags: python, node.js, bash, gruntjs, karma-jasmine

I'm running Jasmine tests in my web app and I want to create a bash script that runs the test and pushes the current code to the remote git repository if there are no failures. Everything is super-duper except the fact that I can't tell if the tests succeeded or failed. How can I do it? If there is no way to do it in bash I can do it in python or nodejs.

I want the code look like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
succeeded=$(grunt test -no_output) #or some thing like it

if[ succeeded = 'True'] than
    git push origin master
fi
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like [grunt uses exit codes](http://gruntjs.com/api/exit-codes) to indicate whether tasks are successful. You can use this to determine whether to push:

```
if grunt test -no_output; then
    git push origin master
fi
```

This tests for a 0 (success) exit code from grunt and pushes if it receives one.

Answer (score 1):

Run command then look at `$?`. Example:

```
if [ $? -eq 0 ]
then
  echo "Successfully created file"
else
 echo "Could not create file" >&2
fi
```